# Function returning pointer to array - cast and get value

Tags: c, function, pointers, return

I have little dilemma with my code.

I have function which returns pointer (uint8_t*) to data buffer. Is it possible and legal to cast this pointer to uint16_t when I need 2 values from array as uint16_t? Or there will be problem with aligning? Buffer is filled via byte reading from I2C.

The problem exists on MCU but when I try this with visualstudio, it´s ok. MCU - Hardfault

```
uint8_t arr[8];

uint8_t * FuncReturnPointer(void)
{
     arr[0] = 0xEE;
     arr[1] = 0xFF;

     return arr;
}

main
{
     uint16_t val16 = 0;

     val16 = *(uint16_t*)FuncReturnPointer();
}
```

Is there something wrong/dangerous?

Comment: Strictly speaking - no, it is not legal because of *strict aliasing*. It *could* be legal in some cases if the original pointer is `char*` and alignment requirements are satisfied. The general advice would be to "manually" compose the resulting `uint16_t` such as  `(arr[1] << 8) + arr[0]` to avoid this and possible endianess issues.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I thought so, that there will be problem.

Comment: Also it ought to be `int main(void)` at least ....

Comment: @alk `arr` is global.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** separate issues here:

- strict aliasing violation
- possible alignment violation

Either of these can lead to various "interesting" phenomena. I could bet that this is due to alignment violation, i.e. `arr` does not happen to reside at an address divisible by `_Alignof(uint16_t)`. The proper fix is to use either

- arithmetic:

  ```
  val16 = ((uint16_t)*address << 8) | (address);
  ```
- `memcpy`:

  ```
  memcpy(&val16, address, sizeof (val16));
  ```